# How to set custom tickMarkShape in flutter slider widget

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make custom tickMarkShape in my flutter project. From docs, I read that it is possible to control tick mark shape with SliderTickMarkShape. But it gives me only one option `SliderTickMarkShape.noTickMark` which removes the tick mark shape, but I would like to make it like a stick. So how can I set custom tick mark shape in flutter?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the docs say: *"Base class for Slider tick mark shapes.

Create a subclass of this if you would like a custom slider tick mark shape.

The tick mark painting can be skipped by specifying noTickMark for SliderThemeData.tickMarkShape."* - so you have to "Create a subclass of this" if you want your own, custom ticks

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to customize the tick as the following image:

[image]

You need to extend `SliderTickMarkShape`. In this case I called LineSliderTickMarkShape. Below is the source code but it is basically a copy of [RoundSliderTickMarkShape](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3b7adb989fc59fd6aa906ee642d749b26f1a4b29/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/slider_theme.dart#L2015), it just changes the [`context.canvas.drawLine`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3b7adb989fc59fd6aa906ee642d749b26f1a4b29/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/slider_theme.dart#L2087) line to customize the shape of the mark. RoundSliderTickMarkShape is the default one.

```
class LineSliderTickMarkShape extends SliderTickMarkShape {
  const LineSliderTickMarkShape({
    this.tickMarkRadius,
  });

  final double? tickMarkRadius;

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize({
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required bool isEnabled,
  }) {
    assert(sliderTheme != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.trackHeight != null);
    assert(isEnabled != null);
    return Size.fromRadius(tickMarkRadius ?? sliderTheme.trackHeight! / 4);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
      PaintingContext context,
      Offset center, {
        required RenderBox parentBox,
        required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
        required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
        required TextDirection textDirection,
        required Offset thumbCenter,
        required bool isEnabled,
      }) {
    Color? begin;
    Color? end;
    switch (textDirection) {
      case TextDirection.ltr:
        final bool isTickMarkRightOfThumb = center.dx > thumbCenter.dx;
        begin = isTickMarkRightOfThumb ? sliderTheme.disabledInactiveTickMarkColor : sliderTheme.disabledActiveTickMarkColor;
        end = isTickMarkRightOfThumb ? sliderTheme.inactiveTickMarkColor : sliderTheme.activeTickMarkColor;
        break;
      case TextDirection.rtl:
        final bool isTickMarkLeftOfThumb = center.dx < thumbCenter.dx;
        begin = isTickMarkLeftOfThumb ? sliderTheme.disabledInactiveTickMarkColor : sliderTheme.disabledActiveTickMarkColor;
        end = isTickMarkLeftOfThumb ? sliderTheme.inactiveTickMarkColor : sliderTheme.activeTickMarkColor;
        break;
    }
    final Paint paint = Paint()..color = ColorTween(begin: begin, end: end).evaluate(enableAnimation)!;

    final double tickMarkRadius = getPreferredSize(
      isEnabled: isEnabled,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
    ).width / 2;
    if (tickMarkRadius > 0) {
      context.canvas.drawLine(Offset(center.dx - 5, center.dy - 5), Offset(center.dx + 5, center.dy + 5), paint);
    }
  }
}
```

Once `LineSliderTickMarkShape` is defined, you can use it to customize your Slider like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliderTheme(
      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
        trackHeight: 20,
          tickMarkShape: const LineSliderTickMarkShape()
      ),
      child: Slider(
      ...
```